# Eclipse - cannot add new connection

Tags: eclipse

I'm using eclipse 4.7.0. And I use run C/C++ remote Application to launch my programs on remote machine (embedded system). I was using it for a while and it worked well.

However, today I couldn't connect, I was prompted for password (which didn't happen before) and after that connection was refused saying No Password provided (while it was saved). I verified that I can connect through ssh.

Then I removed the connection, but when I tried to create it again I couldn't, I filled the new connection wizard window but when I click finish nothing happens, connection is not created.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, OK I solved it myself. restarting the Eclipse changed nothing, but rebooting my PC helped. I still don't know what caused the problem, but I suppose it was something outside Eclipe. Would be nice to get any error message from Eclipse that something is wrong.